# Flutter build ios project failed with unable to read input file as a property list

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

When i open ios module with xcode and try to build project, I get this error: unable to read input file as a property list.

```
environment：
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91, locale zh-Hans-CN) 
    [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)

1. Run `pod install`.
2. build ios module in xcode.

Anyone knows how to solve it please?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEiRD.png
```

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm not familiar with asking questions on this website. This is my error supplementary information: CopyPlistFile /Users/hignton/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-aeubhvwsqszdgyaemhjczyvyovqm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppFrameworkInfo.plist /Users/hignton/Downloads/wesk/ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist

Comment: /Users/hignton/Downloads/wesk/ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    cd /Users/hignton/Downloads/wesk/ios
    builtin-copyPlist --convert binary1 --outdir /Users/hignton/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-aeubhvwsqszdgyaemhjczyvyovqm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app -- /Users/hignton/Downloads/wesk/ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist

error: unable to read input file as a property list: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 1.) (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Comment: You can edit your question to add details instead of adding comments. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `project/ios` directory from the root folder and run this commond

```
flutter create .
```

this will re-create the flutter ios project, now run this project on ios emulator first and then try to build on xcode. It worked for me